# How to align two columns in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to format a personal info list in HTML.
Something like:

```css
.myself p{
 font-size: 130%;
   margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="myself">
<p>Name: First Last<br /><br />Age: 21<br /><br />Movie: xxxxx<br /><br /></p>
</div>
```

but when you run this code, it will look like

```
Name: First Last

    Age: 21

 Movie: xxxxx
```

which basically is centered every line. What I really want to achieve is like this:

```
 Name: First Last

  Age: 21

Movie: xxxxx
```

which align all the ":" colons.
My idea is to make a table, then align each column separately, but I doubt that is the best way to do make this. Hope you guys can give me some better solutions. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this piece of code.

This is called a grid layout, which is currently one of the most used types of layouts ones. The main idea about it is just splitting your page into boxes and stacking them together.

```css
.myself .property{
  width:30%;
  display:inline-block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-align:right;
  }

.myself .value{
  text-align:left;
  padding-left:10px;
  width:70%;
  display:inline-block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  }
```

```html
<div class="myself">
<div class="property">Name:</div><div class="value"> First Last</div> 
<div class="property">Age:</div><div class="value"> 21</div> 
<div class="property">Movie:</div><div class="value"> xxxxxx Last</div> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option instead of using a table is to use the `<dl>` element. Here's a basic example of how it would look:

```css
dl>dt {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: left;
  text-align: right;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: bold;
}

dl>dd {
  margin-left: 160px;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Name:</dt>
  <dd>First Last</dd>
  <dt>Age:</dt>
  <dd>21</dd>
  <dt>Movie:</dt>
  <dd>xxxxx</dd>
</dl>
```

The benefit is less HTML code than what a table would require, and less convoluted. However, if column headers are required, then you should definitely use a `<table>` element.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion there is no problem using a table for simple stuff like these.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="titles"> My name :</td>
        <td>John</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

styles

```
.titles { text-align : right; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution with tables. Not pixel perfect but it should get you started...

```css
#mytable {
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 200px;
}

#mytable td {
border: 1px solid #ddd;
padding: 8px;
}
#mytable .centered{
text-align:center;
} 
#mytable .age{
padding-left:54px;
} 
#mytable .movie{
padding-left:40px;
} 
#mytable tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#mytable tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<table id="mytable"> 
<tr>
 <td class="centered">Name: First Last</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="age">Age: 21</td>  
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="movie">Movie: xxxxx</td>
</tr>
</table>
```