# HTML Align two text columns in web page with different lengh

Tags: html

In a webpage I have this two columns with a picture and some text below. One of the texts is longer than the other which makes the text box longer than the other.

How do I do some padding to make the columns even in a elegant way?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4 mb-xl-0">
          <div class="card card-subject">
            <div class="card-subject__img">
              <img class="card-img rounded-0" src="img/home/subject-1.png" alt="">
              <div class="card-subject__imgOverlay">
                <img src="img/home/hover-icon.png" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-subject__body">
              <h3><a href="#">Employment Law</a></h3>
              <p>This Text i longer than the one This Text i longer than the onenext to it Dominion there fifth fowl eving heaven in life you're over us moved creepeth morn make</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4 mb-xl-0">
          <div class="card card-subject">
            <div class="card-subject__img">
              <img class="card-img rounded-0" src="img/home/subject-2.png" alt="">
              <div class="card-subject__imgOverlay">
                <img src="img/home/hover-icon.png" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-subject__body">
              <h3><a href="#">Personal Injury</a></h3>
              <p>Dominion there fifth fowl eving heaven in life you're over us moved creepeth morn make</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: please provide css or html that matches your problem description

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275925/how-to-align-two-columns-in-html

Answer (score 0):

```css
.card{
    height:60vw;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4 mb-xl-0">
          <div class="card card-subject">
            <div class="card-subject__img">
              <img class="card-img rounded-0" src="img/home/subject-1.png" alt="">
              <div class="card-subject__imgOverlay">
                <img src="img/home/hover-icon.png" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-subject__body">
              <h3><a href="#">Employment Law</a></h3>
              <p>This Text i longer than the one This Text i longer than the onenext to it Dominion there fifth fowl eving heaven in life you're over us moved creepeth morn make</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4 mb-xl-0">
          <div class="card card-subject">
            <div class="card-subject__img">
              <img class="card-img rounded-0" src="img/home/subject-2.png" alt="">
              <div class="card-subject__imgOverlay">
                <img src="img/home/hover-icon.png" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-subject__body">
              <h3><a href="#">Personal Injury</a></h3>
              <p>Dominion there fifth fowl eving heaven in life you're over us moved creepeth morn make</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```